# Dashboards on custom application using application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-sentinel

We have a lot of applications that throws custom logs to application insights. I would like to make a dashboard where I can see if each application is running or throwing exceptions etc. I have tried looking around in log analytics and it does not seem to have a connector to Application insights. Can anyone provide with some information to start on? Should I use Monitor, Log Analytics or Sentinel for this task and how do you get started with custom application insights logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Insights is part of Azure Monitor. When creating a new App Insights resource you can now choose to store everything in an Azure Log Analytics Workspace, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/create-workspace-resource). Or you can [migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource) your existing resource to a workspace backed resource.

Then you can use [workbooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/workbooks-overview) to visualize data using interactive workbooks. These workbooks are also available to classic App Insights resources however.

There is also the possibilty to query an App Insights resource in any Log Analytics Workspace by using the [`app` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query#identifying-an-application) like this:

```
app("name-of-your-ai-resource").requests
| order by timestamp desc
| project timestamp, url, resultCode
```

and use those results for visualizations.

Finally you can also use the rich capabilities of Power Bi to create interactive reposts, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-power-bi)

Comment: So you group multiple App Insights into Log Analytics workbooks?

Comment: In our teams we create workbooks in the seperate application insights resources and include them in the ARM templates. But yes, you can also create an overview of all application insights resources using Log Analytics workbooks